# Open project with several subprojects in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project with the following structure

```
dtu-exam-project/
        ├── README.md
        ├── build_and_run.sh
        ├── docker-compose.yml
        ├── dtu-pay-account
        ├── dtu-pay-client
        ├── dtu-pay-log-api
        ├── dtu-pay-rest-api
        ├── dtu-payment-api
        ├── simple-dtu-pay-client
        └── simple-dtu-pay-server
```

All the folders in `dtu-exam-projects/` are their own independent java projects.

I would like to open a new project in intellij with `dtu-exam-projects/` as the root so that I can navigate to all the other projects within the same winodw. Therefore I click "open project", then naviagte to `dtu-exam-projects/` and click on that. However, when the project has loaded then `simple-dtu-pay-client` is for some reason the root, and I can't navigate to the other projects.
[image]

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you already have `.idea` directory in the project? It may have the project already configured with the wrong content roots. Try deleting this directory and open the directory from scratch. IDE may also try to detect the project configuration automatically and fail. In this case you can add modules and configure the content roots manually per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: thank you! Deleted `.idea` and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE will try to open existing project defined in `.idea` directory. It may contain unexpected modules and content roots configuration.

Deleting this directory will force IDE to initialize the project from scratch when you try to open the root directory next time.

Another option is to open the Project Structure dialog and configured the modules and content roots manually.